# Open the last closed tab in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm new to Android Studio, and wanted to know if there are any shortcut / option to re-open the last closed tab.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

There is no shortcut assigned, but you can easily assign a new one:

Go to `IDE settings | Keymap | Main menu | Window | Editor Tabs | Reopen Closed Tab` (type `reopen` into the filter field to find it faster), right click on that item and select `Add Keyboard Shortcut`

Update: As stated in another answer, you can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> to see a list of all recently viewed files. Additionally, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> to see a list of all recently **edited** files, which is handy when working on multiple files.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Most of the shortcut combinations are already taken :P, I had to conform with ctrl-shift-p.

Comment: Almost all `Alt + Letter` shortcuts are still available ;)

Comment: Any idea why this doesn't work when no files are open?

Comment: @ThomasDavidBaker Whenever some UI works in unexpected ways, it's a bug, because doing thing as expected by a user is the main principle of UI. Feel free to file it to Jetbrains. Probably if everybody were filing tickets. there would be a day when software worked as expected.

Answer (score 30):

For Windows -> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>

For macOS -> <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>

It will show a popup window for the files you visited previously.

Answer (score 13):

The shortcut is <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> on Windows). It correspond to `Navigate` > `Back`.

It will bring your cursor where it was previously, re-opening the tab if needed, and you can do it many times.

Comment: doesn't work when tab was closed without first being in focus....

Answer (score 7):

You may don't have to google this thing.

There are some shortcut given in Android Studio Screen :) :)

[image: Android Studio Says]