# Can Android studio go to previous opened file after i Ctrl+F4 to close current?

Tags: android-studio

It's an interface problem using Android Studio.

Like any other multiple tab application, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to close the current window/ file gets you back to the previous one.

For example, if i edit `MainActivity.java` and switch to `activity_main.xml` I'm used to the behavior that when I click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to close the `activity_main.xml` it goes back to the previous file which is `MainActivity.java` but for some reason (even after I changed the keymap to Visual Studio) it goes back to a random file.

Does anyone know how to change this behavior?

**Before you answer**
I'm not looking for shortcut key to reopen last opened window.
The file is still opened, i'm just looking for the regular behavior that the focus will go to the last file automatically after closing file.

Comment: As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26164872/open-the-last-closed-tab-in-android-studio) it's `CTRL`+`E`

Comment: Please read my edited last part. i'm not looking to re-open file, i've seen this question and it's not what i've been looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

File > Settings > Editor > General > Editor Tabs > When closing active editor > Activate most recently opened tab

Comment: Wow, that is awesome!

Comment: Thank @user2396640, it helps me another issue.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** Consider the other answer first.

---

Okay, I've understood what you're trying to achieve. You want IDE to track the context in real-time. I think that is not present currently. I would first ask in the [`JetBrains IDEA Community Forum`](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200382555-IntelliJ-IDEA-Users) and then go ahead and open a Feature-request on the [IntelliJ IDEA issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA). They actually respond quite fast.

Good Luck!

P.S. Android Studio, in fact, uses IntelliJ IDEA underneath

Comment: Thank you, you are saying that it doesn't exist now? I mean it works on every browser, text editor, or any other microsoft platform